# Range-v3 ranges::to operator custom class (container)

Tags: c++, range, range-v3

I have list of messages and I need to convert to Json them.
And now I use this solution;

Bu I see to<> function. This function generic and I can use vector (iterator)
But how can use custom Adapter?

My solution:

```
vector<MyMessageClass> messages = TODO()
Json::Value json;

ranges::for_each(messages, [&json](const MyMessageClass &msg) {
    json.append(msg.to_json());
});
```

I want

```
vector<MyMessageClass> messages = TODO()
Json::Value json = messages | ranges::to<Json::Value>();
```